# Handling mixed list of values in RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am writing a RestController, where one of the endpoints has to handle the following json:

```
[22, 333, 333, 33, 55, 77.99]
```

These values represent prices, so it would be good to handle them as `BigDecimal`.

I thought something like the snippet below is going to work, but it is not.

```
@PostMapping("/prices")
public void someEndpoint(@ResponseBody List<BigDecimal> prices) {}
```

Perhaps, I should not expect list of BigDecimals, but something else?

Comment: Assuming a wheat-corn costs one million dollar and a wheat-corn burns withing 0.00001 second to ashes inside the sun, you will need over a billion suns to burn all wheatcorns you could possibly buy with a price a bigdecimal could represent. I am pretty sure you do not need bigdecimal for a price.

Comment: @Forin your code is OK - It has one simple mistake. Answer below. I hope it helps.

Comment: Always use BigDecimal when delaing with prices so you can get accurate calculations.

Answer (score 1):

It's a simple mistake with the input: ResponseBody is going out of the REST API, and RequestBody is coming in. So your code will work with:

```
@PostMapping("/prices")
public void someEndpoint(@RequestBody List<BigDecimal> prices) {
  System.out.println(prices); //So you can see the input was received and available
}
```

You can use Double for the prices, if you like - it's a better fit for something like prices. But it's up to you.

Comment: no, dont use doubles as that will run into "over-charging" issues pretty fast.